# Getting an associative array back from prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch an associative array from an SQL query using prepared statements. Nothing i'm trying works. I was able to get it work before I implemented the prepared statements. I'm reading a lot of conflicting information as well as OO and PDO information that doesn't seem to work with procedural code. I may switch over to one of those styles in the future, but I don't want to have to rewrite this whole website right now. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have an item_template.php that reads the data with rows['name'], rows['type'], etc. It was working mysqli_fetch_assoc...I just can't get fetch_assoc to work with the prepared statement.

```
  if ($searchname == NULL) {
    echo 'You must enter something to search for!';
    }else{
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM itemdb WHERE name LIKE ?";
     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: viewresults.php?error=sqlerror2");

        exit();
    }
    else{
      $searchname = "%".$searchname."%";
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s", $searchname);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

      $resultcheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      echo $resultcheck;
        if ($resultcheck == 0) {
          echo 'No results found! Try again! ' . $resultcheck;
          exit();
        }else{
          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
          echo $result;

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {

          include("item_template.php");
          echo "SUCCESS";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `$stmt`? What parameter does `mysqli_fetch_assoc` expect? (Hint it is a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)). `var_dump` is your friend.

Comment: I tried using mysqli_fetch_assoc with mysqli_stmt_store_result with no luck either though. I thought the statement would have been the mysqli_result. I had no issues when I wasn't using prepared statements...Thats what's got me all out of wack. I don't know what i'm doing and I think im confused on something lol. I've been trying to figure this out forever. Most of the examples and help i'm finding are OO and PDO which have just enough differences to not be of help.

Comment: replace while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) with WHILE( null !== ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)))

Comment: Still doesn't work. That's almost the same as what I have just in a different format?

Comment: Your trying to fetch the data from the statement and not the result - `mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)` should be `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`

Answer (score 0):

What encoding are you using in your DB? I use `utf8_general_ci` and cyrillic. So

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

right after `$conn=mysqli_connect();` helps me